# Ubuntu 18.04 opening system setting logs me out

Tags: crash, lock-screen, system-settings, logout, lock

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a dual-boot configuration with Windows 10. I noticed today that, when trying to open system settings, Ubuntu seems to log me out to the lock screen. When I log back in, all previously-running applications are now closed. Very unsure what to do from here, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look in `/var/log/kern.log` and noticed nouveau was crashing about the time I tried to open `gnome-control-center`.

So I installed the latest stable nvidia drivers (I'm using an nvidia graphics card), rebooted and now it works.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Remember to click the grey check mark next to your question to let others know what the solution is.

Comment: Shall do as soon as I’m able (2 days)

Answer (score 2):

When I upgraded to 18.04 same problem happened to me. Ubuntu logs out unexpectedly and even after suspend. I figured out there was something wrong with `.Xauthority`.

First of all remove `.Xauthority` and then relogin using

```
sudo rm -v .Xauthority
sudo service gdm restart
```

Don't worry system will recreate `.Xauthority`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, there's no .Xauthority file in my home directory.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. The file name was .ICEAuthority, though.

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer here, but for me it seemed to be a combo of nVidia drivers, greeter, and theme. When troubleshooting, particularly after an update, try reverting to one of the default themes via Gnome Tweaks, Adwaita, for example. It can sound trivial, but the semi-colon in the wrong place in ubuntu.css can prevent the system from booting.

Answer (score 0):

Like xor7ommy, I found the fix to be a combo of

- Updating the NVidia driver via

  ```
  sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
  ```
- and renaming `.ICEauthority` and restarting.

After that, I was able to open the Ubuntu settings without getting logged out.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem on ubuntu 20.04 and the solution was indeed to update the nvidia driver as proposed by @BillTheITGeek.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

For those wondering where to find the `.ICEauthority`. This is a file found in the home directory. I renamed mine to `.ICEauthority.backup`. After doing these two things i still had the issue, a restart resolved everything. So restarting is required!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same problem. After couple of trials here and there finally able to solve it.

- Go to Additional Drivers
- There click on using X.org server and hit apply changes.
- Restart your system

[image: Link for Additional Drivers Image]